# Construct a square with vertices on a given point, line, and circle.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, geometric-transformation

How to construct a square ABCD given point C, circle and a line so that point A lies on the line and point D lies on the circle?

[image: The constructed square]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Looks like $D$ is on the circle, not $B$.  Anyway, what are your thoughts on the problem?  I guess "use a computer" is not the expected answer?

Comment: Are you given the centre of the circle like in the picture or just the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the problem is solvable.

Rotate a line around $C$ for $45^{\circ}$ and then dilate it with factor ${1\over \sqrt{2}}$. Intersection point between this new line and a circle is a point $D$ (on picture)...

[the square construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3j92.png)
Blue(solid) is what is given; the green is the solution.

- $CL$ is the perpendicular to the line;
- the blue dotted line is the original line $45^{\circ}$ rotated;
- $CN$ is ${1\over \sqrt{2}}$-times $CM$;
- $LN$ intersecting the circle gives us point $D$;
- $CD$ is the first side of the square.

How to perform this spiral similarity in practice? If point $X$ is on a line and let $XZCY$ is a (positive oriented) square with diagonal $XC$, then $X$ maps to $Y$. So take two pointy $X_1$ and $X_2$ on a line and then $Y_1Y_2$ is this new line.